# Sql Query help in confusing structure

Tags: sql

I have to table with blow structures

**Meeting**

- meetingID
- meetingDate
- meetingTitle

**MeetingPersion** the people who attend in Meetings

- id
- meetingID
- personID
- **IsPresent bit**

and this is sample rows for testing

Meeting Table Rows

- meetingID:1 --  2010/05/05 -- MeetingX
- meetingID:2 --  2010/05/07 -- MeetingY

MeetingPerson Table Rows

```
MeetingID:2
PersonID:1
IsPresent:true


MeetingID:2
PersonID:2
IsPresent:true

MeetingID:2
PersonID:3
IsPresent:false

MeetingID:2
PersonID:4
IsPresent:null
```

I need to have query for showing in report and I need to have this result with sample date, title of reporsts

```
MeetingTitle | NumberOfPresent | NumberOfAbsents
```

the result of sample data shoud be like this

```
Title:MeetingX | NumberOfPresent:0 | NumberOfAbsents:0
Title:MeetingY | NumberOfPresent:2 | NumberOfAbsents:1
```

Comment: Your expected output is wrong because There is no `meetingID = 1` available in the table `MeetingPerson`. So it won'g give you this result.

Comment: @hims056 It just means nobody were present at that meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT m.MeetingTitle,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.IsPresent = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumberOfPresent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.IsPresent = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumberOfAbsents
  FROM Meeting m LEFT JOIN MeetingPerson p
    ON m.meetingID = p.meetingID
 GROUP BY m.meetingID
```

Output:

```
| MEETINGTITLE | NUMBEROFPRESENT | NUMBEROFABSENTS |
----------------------------------------------------
|     MeetingX |               0 |               0 |
|     MeetingY |               2 |               1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae2cc/1)** demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
m.meetingtitle
,SUM(CASE WHEN i.ispresent = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numberofabsents
,SUM(CASE WHEN i.ispresent = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numberofabsents
FROM 
meeting m
LEFT OUTER JOIN meetingperson i on i.meetingid = m.meetingid
GROUP BY
m.meetingtitle
```

Comment: It should be outter join I think.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT M.MEETINGTITLE, SUM(CASE WHEN ISPRESENT ISNULL THEN 0 ELSE 1) NumberOfPresent , SUM(CASE WHEN ISPRESENT ISNULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS NOOFABSENTEES
FROM MEETING M INNER JOIN MEETINGPERSON P
WHERE M.MEETINGID=P.MEETINGID
GROUP BY M.MEETINGTITLE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this dynamic query for the same:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when `IsPresent` = ',
      `IsPresent`,
      ' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `IsPresent_',
      `IsPresent`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM MeetingPerson;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT meetingTitle, ', @sql, '
                  FROM Meeting 
             LEFT JOIN MeetingPerson  
                    ON Meeting.meetingID = MeetingPerson.MeetingID
              GROUP BY meetingTitle 
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Result:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ MEETINGTITLE ║ ISPRESENT_1 ║ ISPRESENT_0 ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ MeetingX     ║           0 ║           0 ║
║ MeetingY     ║           2 ║           1 ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1f2c/2)